# why does it say "module does not exist" despite multiple installations

Tags: django, macos, manage.py

I am running the following steps in Mac Terminal:

1. sudo easy_install pip
2. sudo pip install virtualenv
3. virtualenv NameOfFolder
4. cd NameOfFolder
5. source bin/activate
6. sudo pip install django
7. django-admin startproject NameOfFolderSub1
8. cd NameOfFolderSub1
9. python manage.py runserver

At this last steps, it communicates this msg occurred:

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    import django
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

---

Attempted to check the Django version using this command in Terminal:

```
python -m django --version
it confirmed that django is not there with the following msg:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3: No module named django
```

What did I do wrong int he step-by-step installation above ?

Appreciate the help.

The code in manage.py is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "xxx.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError:
        # The above import may fail for some other reason. Ensure that the
        # issue is really that Django is missing to avoid masking other
        # exceptions on Python 2.
        try:
            import django
        except ImportError:
            raise ImportError(
                "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
                "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
                "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
            )
        raise
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: You probably should use `pip3`, and please do *not* use `sudo`, install it with `pip3 install Django --user`.

Comment: Since you have Python 3, the `sudo easy_install pip`/`sudo pip install virtualenv`/`virtualenv NameOfFolder` commands were not required. You can create the virtualenv with `python3 -m venv NameOfFolder`. Then install without sudo as Daniel suggests.

Answer (score 1):

You've done `sudo pip install django`. Don't do that. You're in a virtualenv; just install directly without `sudo`; and use `pip3` instead of `pip`.